# Combining RDD's with some values missing

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

Hi I have two RDD's I want to combine into 1.
The first RDD is of the format

```
//((UserID,MovID),Rating)
val predictions =
model.predict(user_mov).map { case Rating(user, mov, rate) =>
  ((user, mov), rate)
}
```

I have another RDD

```
//((UserID,MovID),"NA")
val user_mov_rat=user_mov.map(x=>(x,"N/A"))
```

So the keys in the second RDD are more in no. but overlap with RDD1. I need to combine the RDD's so that only those keys of 2nd RDD append to RDD1 which are not there in RDD1.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this -

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

// Setting up the rdds as described in the question
case class UserRating(user: String, mov: String, rate: Int = -1)

val list1 = List(UserRating("U1", "M1", 1),UserRating("U2", "M2", 3),UserRating("U3", "M1", 3),UserRating("U3", "M2", 1),UserRating("U4", "M2", 2))

val list2 = List(UserRating("U1", "M1"),UserRating("U5", "M4", 3),UserRating("U6", "M6"),UserRating("U3", "M2"), UserRating("U4", "M2"), UserRating("U4", "M3", 5))

val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(list1)
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(list2)

// Convert to Dataframe so it is easier to handle    
val df1 = rdd1.toDF
val df2 = rdd2.toDF

// What we got:
df1.show
+----+---+----+
|user|mov|rate|
+----+---+----+
|  U1| M1|   1|
|  U2| M2|   3|
|  U3| M1|   3|
|  U3| M2|   1|
|  U4| M2|   2|
+----+---+----+

df2.show
+----+---+----+
|user|mov|rate|
+----+---+----+
|  U1| M1|  -1|
|  U5| M4|   3|
|  U6| M6|  -1|
|  U3| M2|  -1|
|  U4| M2|  -1|
|  U4| M3|   5|
+----+---+----+

// Figure out the extra reviews in second dataframe that do not match (user, mov) in first    
val xtraReviews = df2.join(df1.withColumnRenamed("rate", "rate1"), Seq("user", "mov"), "left_outer").where("rate1 is null")

// Union them. Be careful because of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32705056/what-is-going-wrong-with-unionall-of-spark-dataframe

def unionByName(a: DataFrame, b: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    val columns = a.columns.toSet.intersect(b.columns.toSet).map(col).toSeq
    a.select(columns: _*).union(b.select(columns: _*))
}

// Final result of combining only unique values in df2    
unionByName(df1, xtraReviews).show

+----+---+----+
|user|mov|rate|
+----+---+----+
|  U1| M1|   1|
|  U2| M2|   3|
|  U3| M1|   3|
|  U3| M2|   1|
|  U4| M2|   2|
|  U5| M4|   3|
|  U4| M3|   5|
|  U6| M6|  -1|
+----+---+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

It might also be possible to do it in this way:

1. RDD's are really slow, so read your data or convert your data in dataframes.
2. Use spark `dropDuplicates()` on both the dataframes like `df.dropDuplicates(['Key1', 'Key2'])` to get distinct values on keys in both of your dataframe and then
3. simply union them like `df1.union(df2)`.

Benefit is you are doing it in spark way and hence you have all the parallelism and speed.